# Shorten sed sustitution or possible alternative

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

I've some data being fed in few files. The requirement is to format the textual contents in these files and add newlines post formatting.

Requirement of substitution:

```
Text      | Substituted
-----------------------
@Network  | #Network
@ Network | #Network
@Daemon   | #Daemon
@ Daemon  | #Daemon
@Service  | #Service
@ Service | #Service
----------------------
```

I've tried using sed to do this, but the command gets huge and cluttered, as the substitution is not limited to only letters N,D & S and more and more Capital Alphabets gets added day by day in the requirement.

```
cat results_090316.out | sed -e 's/  //g' -e 's/@N/#N/g' -e 's/@S/#S/g' -e 's/@D/#D/g' -e 's/@ N/#N/g' -e 's/@ S/#S/g' -e 's/@ D/#D/g' | tr '#' '\n'
```

If sed is not the proper tool to perform such substitutions, could you suggest an alternative?

The code is written in bash on RHEL 6 / Solaris 10 OS.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Marcos: `sed 's/@ */#/' file` ?

Comment: @Cyrus , I can't use @ *, as I don't want to substitute all letters.. it's a chosen that needs to be substituted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of tool is alright, but you're not using the full power of regular expressions. For example, below I use a "character class" to create a custom group of characters to match, *e.g.* `[NSD]`, and then use a "backreference" (`\1`) by first "capturing" a piece of the search (with `\(` and `\)`):

```
cat results_090316.out | sed -e 's/  //g' -e 's/@\([NSD]\)/#\1/g' -e 's/@ \([NSD]\)/#\1/g' | tr '#' '\n'
```

But we can do better and use the `?` "quantifier" (zero or one of the predecessing atom) to combine even the no-space and space cases:

```
cat results_090316.out | sed -e 's/  //g' -e 's/@ \?\([NSD]\)/#\1/g' | tr '#' '\n'
```

Comment: I tried something similar earlier, but I guess I was incorrect in it's utilization.. sed -e 's/@[NSD]/#[NSD]/g', which was giving wrong output.

Comment: Your attempt is indeed an intuitive way to go, and would make regular expressions easier (but less powerful, since you'd always need to have a 1-to-1 mapping). One power of backreferences is that you can capture as many things as you need with additional `\(\)` and reorder them in the substitution like `\3\2\1`, which would get confusing if the syntax were as you tried.

Comment: Note that you can make your expression even stricter by using another thing called "Alternation" instead of character classes: `-e 's/@ ?\(Network\|Daemon\|Service\)/#\1/g'`. This technique of using `\|` is basically character classes except for entire words.

Comment: @AndrewCheong `?` needs escaping.

Comment: Thanks @123. Always a pain to adjust to GNU grep.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Huh? Thats posix compliant.

Comment: @123 - Then I have my words mixed up. Thought GNU basic grep was what required the backslashes for quantifiers like in vim.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it using a character class and optional space matching:

```
sed 's/  //g; s/@ *\([NDS]\)/#\1/g' results_090316.out
```

Comment: I tried it, but I guess I was incorrect in it's utilization.. sed -e 's/@[NSD]/#[NSD]/g', which was giving wrong output.

Comment: You have to copy/paste the exact sed command I provided above.

Comment: `[NSD]` is called character class and it will only work in regex patter not in replacement as you've shown in your comment. Try my suggested command **as is** and see the results